# How To Remove Brotli Compression and Gzip Compression from a Directory with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, litespeed, brotli, openlitespeed

My hosting plan is cPanel with OpenLiteSpeed instead of Apache. I turned on Compress All Content setting in cPanel. This appears to use gzip in some places, brotli in others. Now I need to prevent some directories from having this compression. The .htaccess rule I was given by my hosting plan was:

```
RemoveOutputFilter DEFLATE html txt xml css js php
```

However, when I visit the website and then check Chrome Dev Tools > Network and click on the homepage, I still see Content-Encoding: br, indicating Brotli is still engaged. So, doing some tests, I tried the following and they all fail too:

```
RemoveOutputFilter BROTLI_COMPRESS;DEFLATE html txt xml css js php
RemoveOutputFilter BROTLI_COMPRESS DEFLATE html txt xml css js php
# place the following as a second line under RemoveOutputFilter DEFLATE html txt xml css js php
RemoveOutputFilter BROTLI_COMPRESS html txt xml css js php
# place the following as a second line under RemoveOutputFilter DEFLATE html txt xml css js php
RemoveOutputFilter BROTLI html txt xml css js php
# place the following as a second line under RemoveOutputFilter DEFLATE html txt xml css js php
RemoveOutputFilter BR html txt xml css js php
```

How do I turn off all compression on a given directory using .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cPanel with OpenLiteSpeed instead of Apache.

I assume you mean the LiteSpeed Enterprise , as OpenLiteSpeed won't work with cPanel

```
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
  SetEnv no-brotli
  SetEnv no-gzip 1 
</IfModule>
```

try this to `.htaccess`  should disable both BR and GZIP

Comment: Question. Why does the no-gzip have a 1 on it, while the no-brotli does not?

Comment: good question and I do not know , just search and find them in LiteSpeed doc/wiki  :)

Comment: Yep, I searched and it said that the number is not necessary on the no-brotli one.